# Issiue with ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: mysql

I have a question about ON DELETE CASCADE, i have made thise tables as an example.

```
CREATE TABLE shop_articles(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    description TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE shop_articles_images(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    article_id INT,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    image VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES shop_articles (id)
);
```

In order to delete all the data affiliated with the main table, i am using this ALTER TABLE command after adding the tables.

```
ALTER TABLE shop_articles_images
ADD CONSTRAINT shop_articles_images_ibf5
FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES shop_articles (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It seams alltough this have been added i cant delete rows from the main table, i dont want to manually delete the other affiliated tables, but delete it when delete from the main table.

Any one have experience with this, or can see what i do wrong here? does this altertable reset when the mysql server is restarted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some confusion about how `ON DELETE CASCADE` works.  If your engine is MyISAM, which does not enforce foreign keys, then no cascading deletes will happen.  If your engine is InnoDB, then if you delete a record from the main table `shop_articles` then any records in `shop_articles_images` which are linked to the main table via a key relationship will also be deleted.

Comment: My tables are InnoDB, and like stated aboue the tables have relations.

Comment: What does this show you: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks'` ?  Foreign key checks must be turned on in order for cascading to be carried out.

Comment: foreign_key_checks  ON

Comment: seams that it all works well now, i removed the FOREIGN KEY (article_id) REFERENCES shop_articles (id) from the table create.

Comment: Happy to help you out.  At least we were able to turn over every stone.